# Получить периоды из таблицы

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица (много строк)

```
------------------------------------
| id |  cId  |        time         |
------------------------------------
| 1  |   5   | 2017-06-01 10:00:00 |
| 2  |   5   | 2017-06-01 10:01:00 |
| 3  |   5   | 2017-06-01 10:06:00 |
| 7  |   5   | 2017-06-01 10:08:00 |
| 4  |   2   | 2017-07-01 10:05:00 |
| 5  |   2   | 2017-07-01 10:06:00 |
| 6  |   2   | 2017-07-01 10:07:00 |
------------------------------------
```

Как получить периоды, продолжительность которых больше 180 секунд.

```
---------------------------------------------------
| cId |        begin        |         end         |
---------------------------------------------------
|  5  | 2017-06-01 10:01:00 | 2017-06-01 10:06:00 |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select cId,min(time) begin,max(time) end
  from `Table5`
 group by cId
having time_to_sec(timediff(max(time),min(time)))>180
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.cid, MIN(b.time) begin, MIN(e.time) end
    FROM foo b INNER JOIN foo e ON (b.cid = e.cid AND b.id < e.id)
    GROUP BY b.cid, b.id
    HAVING TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(MIN(e.time), MIN(b.time))) > 180;
```

Рабочий пример на [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/457b5/13)